# ReactJS URL changing but not the page w/ BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So, I know there's a lot of questions about this and I've been searching for a solution for a long time, but nothing seems to work and I'm almost a beginner in ReactJS...

When I click on my button, the URL link changes, but the page is still the same. I'm trying to build a game (a quizz actually) which has some levels, so the component is always the same but with different data.

To explain better:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {dataSet1, dataSet2} from './data/dataSet.js'
import Quiz from './Quiz.js'
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route, Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var style = {
      width: "25%",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      float: "center",
      padding: "12px 28px",
      textAlign: "center",
      color: "white",
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Button style={style} component={Link} to="/level1">Play</Button>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/level1" component={withRouter(Quiz)}>
              <Quiz level={1} data={dataSet1}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/level2" component={withRouter(Quiz)}>
              <Quiz level={2} data={dataSet2}/>
            </Route>
          </Switch>  
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Quiz.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

class Quiz extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {current:0, level: props.level, dataSet:props.data, correct:0, incorrect:0}
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)

    }

    handleClick(choice) {
        if (choice === this.state.dataSet[this.state.current].correct) {
          this.setState({correct: this.state.correct + 1})
        } else {
          this.setState({incorrect: this.state.incorrect + 1})
        }

        if (this.state.current === 4) { 
            if(this.state.correct + this.state.incorrect === 4){ 
                this.setState({current: this.state.current}) 
            }
            else {
                this.setState({current: 0})
                this.setState({incorrect: 0})
                this.setState({correct: 0})
            }
        } else {
             this.setState({current: this.state.current + 1}) 
        }
      }

      render() { 
        var style = {
            width: "25%",
            display: "block",
            backgroundColor: "green",
            textAlign: "center",
            color: "white"
          }
        if(this.state.current === 4 && this.state.correct === 5 ){
            var l = this.state.level + 1
            var next = '/level' + l
            return(
                <div>
                    <ScoreArea correct={this.state.correct} incorrect={this.state.incorrect} />
                    <h3 align="left">Passaste de nível!</h3>
                    <Button style={style} component={Link} to={next}>
                        Next Level
                    </Button>
                </div>
            )
        } 
        else {
            return(
                <div>
                  <ScoreArea correct={this.state.correct} incorrect={this.state.incorrect} />
                  <QuizArea handleClick={this.handleClick} dataSet={this.state.dataSet[this.state.current]} />
                </div>
              )
        }        
      }
}

....

export default withRouter(Quiz);
```

When I click on "Next Level" my URL changes to *http://localhost:3000/level2* but the page isn't changing. Although, if I refresh the page, it works just fine and my page is rendered as it should be. Also, if I click on "Play" when I'm in my level2 route, the same happens: the URL changes to *http://localhost:3000/level1* but my page is showing me level2.

Resuming:

I can't go to level1 from level2 or to level2 from level1 without refreshing the page.

If someone could help me, it would be great.

Comment: does your ```Quiz.js``` do anything with the ```props``` you are providing? Unfortunately you skipped this part of your code...

Comment: I changed the code rn. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thank you, I will post an answer in a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I was able to fix it by doing a very simple thing with "href".

So, I updated this:

```
<Button style={style} component={Link} to={next}>
  Next Level
</Button>
```

To this:

```
<Button href={next} style={style} >
  Next Level
</Button>
```

And now it's working just fine!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues that you ran into here.

The first one is that you are putting props into state. This usually isn't a good practice and should be avoided, so you don't get issues like this one. In this case it is completely unjustified to put `props.level` and `props.data` in state, because you aren't modifying it at all).

The second one is React Router being intelligent and choosing not to remount your component. You didn't specify a `key` prop to your `Route` components, which indicated that the `Quiz` components inside are the same thing, thus only the props should be changed.

Thankfully we only have to resolve the first one, because the component won't need to remount then, because there will be no state that would need to be changed.

Here is the solution: 
**Quiz.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

class Quiz extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {current:0, correct:0, incorrect:0} //removed the unnecessary state 
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)

    }

    handleClick(choice) {
        if (choice === this.props.data[this.state.current].correct) {
          this.setState({correct: this.state.correct + 1})
        } else {
          this.setState({incorrect: this.state.incorrect + 1})
        }

        if (this.state.current === 4) { 
            if(this.state.correct + this.state.incorrect === 4){ 
                this.setState({current: this.state.current}) 
            }
            else {
                this.setState({current: 0})
                this.setState({incorrect: 0})
                this.setState({correct: 0})
            }
        } else {
             this.setState({current: this.state.current + 1}) 
        }
      }

      render() { 
        var style = {
            width: "25%",
            display: "block",
            backgroundColor: "green",
            textAlign: "center",
            color: "white"
          }
        if(this.state.current === 4 && this.state.correct === 5 ){
            var l = this.props.level + 1
            var next = '/level' + l
            return(
                <div>
                    <ScoreArea correct={this.state.correct} incorrect={this.state.incorrect} />
                    <h3 align="left">Passaste de nível!</h3>
                    <Button style={style} component={Link} to={next}>
                        Next Level
                    </Button>
                </div>
            )
        } 
        else {
            return(
                <div>
                  <ScoreArea correct={this.state.correct} incorrect={this.state.incorrect} />
                  <QuizArea handleClick={this.handleClick} dataSet={this.props.data[this.state.current]} />
                </div>
              )
        }        
      }
}

....

export default withRouter(Quiz);
```

(Just replaced all `this.state.level` with `this.props.level` and all `this.state.dataSet` with `this.props.data`)

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, something changed but it doesn't resolve my problem :( now, I click "next level", the URL changes to "/level2" and if I click again the URL changes to "/level3" but the page is still the same. do you thing that if I show you the rest of the code below the handleClick() it would help?

Comment: Do you have more routes to support more levels? In the question you only have 2 `Routes`, so "/level3" shouldn't work. If the switch between level 1 and 2 works correctly, you won't need to send any extra code.

Comment: In the code you provided there is no "/level3" route at all, so there is no way it will appear.